# Redirecting user based on the query parameter passsed on the login screen

Tags: wp-redirect

https://site/login?tokenreq=https://thirdparyt.com/docs/file.pdf

Based on the tokenrequest parameter how to redirect to the file.pdf link
So far tried

```
    function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {


    print_r($_POST);
      
    echo $_REQUEST['tokenRequest'];exit;
  if(isset($_GET['tokenRequest'])){ 
    $token_request_url = $_GET['tokenRequest']; 
   
    wp_redirect($token_request_url.'/?token='.xxxx);
    exit;

  } else {
    wp_redirect('/dashboard');
    exit;
     } 
 }
 add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
```